# Function tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices result on an error

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I just implemented my first GAN to generate some 128x128 images. I have done some successful tests using a dataset of 500 images. Now, I want to test my GAN with more images (80k) but when I run this :

```
BUFFER_SIZE = 10000
BATCH_SIZE = 1000

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_imgs).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

I got this error : `Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.`

With 500 images, I got no errors.
I have read that this type of errors is typically caused by a lack of hardware (memory usage...) but the problem is that the server on which I'm running this got 64Go of RAM and a GTX 1080Ti as GPU. When I print the GPU memory usage (VRAM) I'm getting some totally normal values (I'm using like 20% of total VRAM usage).

So, where do you think is the problem is ?

Comment: I'd try with a much lower batch size, maybe 256 to begin with (or even lower), and then you can try with a higher one if you want

Comment: Your data still has to go to the GPU right? Maybe that doesn't have enough memory. You can try 2 things. 1. Lower batch size. 2. Use `tf.dataset` as a generator

Comment: What's the vram usage during training and before it fails? Is it still 20%?